# Cannot insert data from frontend Javascript to database using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on an Node.js-Express.js-Mongoose application.
I want to accept user details (Name and Age)  in an html form (EJS file), save into databse (using mongoose) display the added user details on the webpage .
I am using AJAX for the same. The files used are :

**userview.ejs** (contains the Form) --> **frontend.js** (uses jquery) --> **users.js** (router file- calls the add() function defined in the userController)    -->  **userController.js** (attached below) --> **userService.js** (performs DB operations).

Check the image of how the list should look like. 
[image: User Form]

What actually happens is that a new user is created but the name isnt displayed.

[image: Blank Entries]

A peek into database shows that only IDs of the blank entries are added.
[image: Mongodb snapshot]

**FRONTEND.js**

```js
console.log('Frontend Reached');

$(document).ready(function() {

  var url = '/users/delete_user';
  var user_url = '/users/add_user';


  function load_users(e) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'userview.ejs',
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'post',
      ContentType: 'html',
      data: $('#user_form').serialize(), 
      success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#list').html(data);
        //$('#user_form').submit( load_users );
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

//ADDING A USER

```js
  $(document).on('click', '.btn btn-success', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user_name = $("#nameinput").val();
    var user_age = $("#ageinput").val();
    console.log(user_name);
    console.log(user_age);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'userview.ejs',
      dataType: 'text',
      type: 'post',
      ContentType: 'html',
      data: {
        'user_name': user_name,
        'user_age': user_age
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        console.log(data);
        load_users();
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault();


  }); //onclick



}); //document ready
```

This is **userController.js**
Console logging in this file shows that the record is undefined.

```js
var User = require('../models/usermodel.js');
var userService = require('../services/userService');

var userController = {
  add: function(request, response) {
    var user_name = request.body.user_name;
    var user_age = request.body.user_age;
    console.log(user_name);   //SHOWS UNdEFINED
    var newUser = new User({
      name: user_name,
      age: user_age
    });
    console.log(newUser);
    //var userName = request.body.user_name;
    //var userAge = request.body.user_age;
    userService.add(newUser, function(err, added) {
      if (err != null) {
        response.send(500);
      } else {
        response.send(200);
      }
    });
  },

  delete: function(request, response) {

    var userId = request.body.user_id;
    userService.delete(userId, function(err, deleted) {
      if (err != null) {
        response.send(500);
      } else {
        response.send(200);
      }
    });
  }
};

module.exports = userController;
```

Comment: What error? What is the problem? What should happen? What actually happens? This is what makes a question, and is lacking from yours. See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to improve your question.

Comment: Are you trying to add data directly from frontend to mongodb? I'm unable to find a reason for that, sir! You need to either have open (not secured) DB or to store credentials in frontend (meaning pretty much open DB since you can't hide anything on frontend). That's a no go.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have made the necessary changes. Please let me know if u need anything else.

Comment: maybe the problem is the `dataType` and `ContentType` you're setting. remove them to leave as default or change to `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and `dataType: "json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send your data using **JSON.stringify()**,
and specify the content-type to **'application/json'** so your server will know to expect a JSON.

```
var data = {
    'user_name': user_name,
    'user_age': user_age
  },

$.ajax({
  url: 'userview.ejs',
  type: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data), 
  success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
    console.log(data);
    load_users();
  },
  error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: Same issue persists. I get a Deprecation warning and the error below:
Use res.sendStatus(status) instead at controllers\userController.js:21:34
User created!
POST /users/add_user 200 14149.870 ms - 2

Comment: Do you still have that issue? @ArjunJain